# How to cancel ES2020 dynamic import?

Tags: javascript, import, promise, xmlhttprequest

ES2020 introduced [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports), that work like so:

```
import('/modules/my-module.js')
  .then((module) => {
    // Do something with the module.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Do something with the error.
  });
```

Let's say the user has started importing the module, but then they decide to cancel out. How do I stop the request from continuing downloading the requested module?

Comment: Why would you let the user decide that? And you can just decide not to use it

Comment: @mplungjan say a user opens a part of an app that requires some lazy-loaded content. The dynamic import starts. However, they may have done so by mistake, or they may have changed their mind. The lazy-loaded part may take quite a bit to download because it's several MBs (could be the reason why it's lazy-loaded) or because they have a slow connection, etc. Of course it's async, and you can decide not to use it – but sometimes it can be better to abort the request in the first place.

Comment: One idea,.. fetch requests can be aborted.  So you could maybe try doing a fetch first, when complete then do the dynamic import.  Because the fetch has already cached the javascript file, the dynamic import should then be instant.  One thing to bear in mind doing this, if you just ignore the promise and let it complete instead it will end up caching the file, so if the user ends up changing his mind again, this will end up taking less download bandwidth.  So do be mindful of aborting downloads, as that's wasting bandwidth in the long run..